# What would you call the behavior of a company or its management engaged in meaningless job opportunity?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What would you call the behavior of a company or its mid management wherein the company is specialized in Activity A in their home country “a”, but relentlessly keeps on attempting to venture without a vision in business opportunity in activity comprising AB in country “b”, activity comprising BC in country “a” or DC in country “e”, where B, C and so on… are activities completely outside their capability.

All this is done with no research, no feasibility check but just jumping for any opportunity.

**Background** : Mid management really isn’t honestly interested in anything but collecting their hefty paycheck and huge bonus but this is just to show top management that they are involved in some big ventures.

Top management has give the mid management free hand due to its remote location and its technical knowhow.

The disinterest is displayed by their lack in guiding the first line officers in any way who are deputed for securing such business opportunity but usually push them under the bus.

Management isn’t inclined in market research and thus does not understand how Activity sector “A” works, management policies are to keep first line knowledgeable officers in busy work rather than meaningful work.

The end result is they fail 99.99% in their venture due to lack of past performance thus lack of qualification, even in activity A in home country “a” due to spreading too thin and first line officers are frustrated of thankless & meaningless tasks and disgruntled.

Comment: This comes across as a rambling, personal moan about the place where you work, and your example including "a", "b", "AB", "BC" etc is very confusing.  This could be a genuine question but you need to boil it down to be more precise, shorter, less confusing and with an example sentence.

Comment: Sorry but this is to cite the sort of wrongdoing to a law firm for including the subject in legal matters. I am fully aware this is not the forum for rambling and moaning.

Comment: my suggestions for improving your question still hold.

Comment: I'd call it "typical".

Answer (score 2):

[**Gross negligence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_negligence)

and

**[Profiteering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiteering_(business))**  OR  operating on **personal agendas**  that resulted in huge

[**opportunity costs**](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/opportunitycost.asp)

If you are looking for the right term to qualify the type of wrongdoing to a lawyer, I suggest you explain your scenario and let them figure out the technical terms for the nature of wrongdoing(s).